# Use ColdFusion to pull in WP.com posts?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, api

Is it possible to pull in Wordpress.com posts into an external site, in this instance, ColdFusion?  Is there a REST API for it?

If not, is there another solution to pull in content?

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine you could grab the RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the WordPress RSS feed to pull in posts or enable the XML-RPC interface which will allow you to access content directly.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript: http://code.google.com/apis/feed/

php: http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/